# Finding volume of solid associated to a base with a parabolic region

Tags: calculus

I know how to slice a disk, washer, or shell to find total volume or infinitesimal volume. But this problem here is worded so weirdly to me I don't understand what it's really asking me to do. I don't even understand what my cross sections will look like.

> Use calculus to find the volume of the following solid S: The base of S is the parabolic region $\{(x,y)\vert x^2 \le y \le 1\}$. Cross sections perpendicular to the y-axis are squares.

Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: Never post unsearchable images bearing text.  Instead show courtesy and typeset (using *MathJax*).

Comment: The goal is to find cross sectional area in the direction you're integrating since infinitesimal volume is always area $\times dx$. In the case of washers, the cross sectional area was a circle. For shells it was a rectangle (the side of a cylinder). What will it be here?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork fixed.

Comment: @NinadMunshi, I used a height of dy and a length of x, rewrote x in terms of y to get the root of y. then took the area of that, $\sqrt{y}*dy$ and summed it from 0 to 1 and got myself 2/3. It was marked wrong though. Only other thing I'm able to come up with is $dv=dy^2$, but that doesn't sound right

Comment: Don't you need to know the extent in the $z$ direction too?  Didn't they specify that?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork they did not

Answer (score 0):

This figure, showing a slice, may help:

[image]

This cross section is a general *rectangle* (not necessarily a square) because we are given no limits on $z$.

Frankly, the problem makes no sense without the $z$ limits specified, and should be closed until it is.

Comment: Isn't this a rectangular slice, though?